# How to decode utf file name in python email?

Tags: python, email, decode

I use [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) code for unpack email file , the part of **unpack a MIME message** but my problem is with uft file names like:

```
=?utf-8?B?2YbYs9iu2YcgINin2YTYrdin2YLZitmHINmC2LHYp9ix2K/Yp9ivINin2LM=?= =?utf-8?B?2KrYp9mG2K/Yp9ix2K8g2LPYp9iy2YogMTExMTEuZG9jeA==?=
```

It is make program crash at

```
fp = open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'wb')
```

with

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

because it contain unacceptable characters ,or i think it is because of that.it is nothing like this [site](http://www.base64decode.org/) can decode.

The first problem is to pass this error the second problem is to decode the file name.

Comment: That's not UTF, it's [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). And it's not a filename, it's the file contents itself.

Comment: Actually, that's [RFC2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) encoding. It doesn't look like a file name, maybe a subject line? But I don't read Arabic so I can't really tell.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it is the part which fill filename section of the code.no it is file name it is some kind of Arabic character.

Comment: @tripleee it is actually a file name.I saw it in the original email file,

Answer (score 0):

[`email.header.decode_header(header)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html) accepts a string, and returns a list of tuples in the form `[(text, encoding), ...]` where `encoding` is `None` for a piece which wasn't encoded (and thus ostensibly had an `ascii` encoding).

Comment: what should i import ? in the header.

Comment: Did you read the linked documentation? The example has `from email.header import decode_header` so that's probably good for a start.

Comment: it return [('None', None)]

Comment: with the charachter i write it return some thing like his **86\xd8\xb3\xd8\xae\xd9\x87  \xd8\xa7\xd9\x8**

Comment: That's an invalid fragment but at quick glance, it looks like UTF-8.

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51545/discussion-with-shombol-shagol)